# Validation among the sheets in Excel using macro

Tags: excel, for-loop, foreach, vba

I want to create a macro which Compares data between the sheets.

I have data in the Sheet1 under Column A (Size of row / length is not constant) which needs to be compared with the data available in the Sheet2 under Column A. If that particular cell is matching then I would require the data next to the column A in Sheet1 (i.e. Column B in Sheet1) to be pasted in the column C (Sheet1). I'm trying to write a macro using the If and Loop but I fail and I forgot to save the macro I wrote.

When I use INDEX MATCH Excel becomes slow. Also I got up a new criterion now regards to my data. If column A in first sheet is matched with column A in second sheet then I want the column B to be validated with that off in second sheet and if both the conditions are satisfied then I want a value in column C.

I believe this complications can be sorted with macros loop or For each Next. I'm not sure about it.

Please sort it for me.

Comment: Please sort it for me..? No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to modify this slightly to work with your data but it should do the trick(based on my understanding of your problem).

```
Sub compare()

Dim i As Integer

i = 1

For Each cell1 In Sheet1.Range("A1:A100")

    For Each cell2 In Sheet2.Range("A1:A100")

        If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

        Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value = cell1.Value
        i = i + 1

        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I face an issue with it.. If i run the macro, it doesn't stop at the A100 and it randomly goes till Row 1000. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Hmm... not sure. Are you still having this issue? I had an issue with it find multiples of the same result in the 2nd sheet and returning it as a match multiple times in sheet 3, but wasn't entirely sure if that problem would effect you. If I get time I'll try and look at it some more.

Comment: Thanks !! Awaiting for your reply